# Vagrant forward a range of ports

Tags: port-forwarding, vagrant

Is there a way to forward a range of ports using vagrant 1.2.1 or higher? I know that you can forward any number of ports individually by using

```
config.vm.forward_port 80, 4567
```

Or, is the answer simply don't use vagrant to do such a thing?

Comment: Does this help? http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html

Comment: Not exactly. Wanted to know if you can specify a range of ports to be open, rather than one at a time. Perhaps I'll contact the author directly.

Comment: Since the Vagrantfile is just a Ruby script you might be able to write a for loop that executes config.vm.forward_port for every port you want. I'm not fluent in Ruby, so I can't really help you with code.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If anyone needs an example of how to do the loop in your Vagrantfile here it is:

```
for i in 64000..65535
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: i, host: i
end
```

The above loop will forward all ports between 64000 and 65535 to the exact same port on the guest (note that 64000 and 65535 are inclusive).

Comment: On my computer vagrant was a bit long to map 1000 ports. Unless you really need so many mapped ports, you should map 50 ports.

Comment: @Antoine yes I've noticed that it is very slow as well. I normally end up just using 10 to 20 for development boxes.

Comment: Extremely slow to check used ports on windows, errors out once the command line limitation kicks in.

Comment: @AlexanderT how many ports are you trying to forward?

Comment: @ddelrio1986 around a thousand.

Comment: @AlexanderT ready my comment above. You would normally want to only forward 10 or so on a development box due to how slow it is to setup a port forward with Vagrant.

Comment: @ddelrio1986 yeah, well it works fine on Linux. I don't think this is an unsolvable problem, just that Vagrant haven't solved it yet.

Answer (score 2):

The 'for' examples above are correct for doing an inclusive range. If you would like to forward a set of specific ports, you need to use the Ruby .each operator.

The variables can go inside or outside of the main Vagrant.configure loop.

```
UDP_PORTS_LIST={
  "5000" => 5000, # Some service
}

TCP_PORTS_LIST={
  "5900" => 5900, # VNC
}
```

The loops need to go inside the Vagrant.configure block for the VM you want to map them for (remember you can have multiple VMs in a single Vagrantfile).

```
UDP_PORTS_LIST.each do |guest, host|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: "#{guest}", host: "#{host}", protocol: "udp"
end
TCP_PORTS_LIST.each do |guest, host|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: "#{guest}", host: "#{host}", protocol: "tcp"
end
```